# Skip same id during MongoDB insertMany

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way of telling MongoDB to skip (instead of crashing) if we want to insert a document which has the same `_id` as an existing one?

Say, I have this list and I want to persist it:

```
to_mongo = [
    {'_id': 'aaaaaa', 'content': 'hey'},
    {'_id': 'bbbbbb', 'content': 'you'},
    {'_id': 'aaaaaa', 'content': 'hey'}
]

mongo_collection.insert_many(to_mongo)
```

I'd like the last item to be simply ignored, instead of causing the whole request to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ordered=False` in the **[`insert_many()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many)** method i.e.

```
to_mongo = [
    {'_id': 'aaaaaa', 'content': 'hey'},
    {'_id': 'bbbbbb', 'content': 'you'},
    {'_id': 'aaaaaa', 'content': 'hey'}
]
mongo_collection.insert_many(to_mongo, ordered=False)
```

This makes sure that all write operations are attempted, even if there are errors. From the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many):

> *ordered* (optional): If True (the default) documents will be inserted
>   on the server serially, in the order provided. If an error occurs all
>   remaining inserts are aborted. If False, documents will be inserted on
>   the server in arbitrary order, possibly in parallel, and all document
>   inserts will be attempted.